# Parse complicated XML with c# Xml to linq

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, linq

Im a newbie when it comes to parsing XML documents.
I have the following XML document i want to parse: http://www.petrol.eu/api/fuel_prices.xml

And get the price for

Currently i am using the following code:

```
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://www.petrol.eu/api/fuel_prices.xml");
        var list = xDoc.Descendants("country").Where(t => t.Attribute("label").Value=="Slovenia").ToList();

        foreach (var country in list)
        {
            var s95 = country.Elements("pricetype").First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "price").Value;
            txtBVnosi.Text = s95;
        }
```

I know the code is wrong.I am kinda lost now because i don't know how to properly get the prices out as it is quite a complicated structured XML and every other question i found was for simpler XML files.

Comment: Use xml schema(generate xsd) & parse it.
Or You can user this [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: @sushmitgos this wouldn't solve OP's problem. The XML is not malformed or invalid, he just didn't find any element.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann.. Ahh right!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to look into the `fuel` elements to retrieve the price.

To get all prices for each type of fuel, I suggest using a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> prices = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var fuel in country.Elements("fuel"))
{
    prices.Add(
        fuel.Attribute("type").Value,
        fuel.Element("priceType").Elements().First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "price").Value);
}
```

After that, you can easily get a specific price:

```
var s95 = prices["95"];
```

But since I guess (based on the name of the variable in your code) you want to get the price for the fuel type 95, this query would also work:

```
var s95 = country.Elements("fuel")
                 .First(f => f.Attribute("type").Value == "95")
                 .Element("priceType")
                 .Elements()
                 .First(p => p.Attribute("type").Value == "price").Value;
```